# Are the canonical representatives of the Hilbert space $L^2$ basis-dependent?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

The space $\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of functions $f$ such that $\int |f(x)|^p\, d^nx$ converges is only a seminormed rather than a normed vector space, because any function $f$ whose support has Lebesgue measure zero has $||f||_p := \int |f(x)|^p\, d^nx = 0$, even if $f$ is not identically zero. In order to turn it into a normed vector space [$L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces), we need to [mod out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)) by the kernel of the $p$-norm, which is the set of functions whose support has Lebesgue measure zero (or equivalently, we need to identify functions that agree almost everywhere).

This raises the natural question of whether this quotient space $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ has a natural [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Notation_and_formal_definition); that is, whether for every equivalence class $[f] \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ there is a natural canonical representative square-integrable function $f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is there generally a natural section of $\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ space? (I'm using the word "natural" loosely, not in any kind of mathematically precise sense.)

For the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with a given orthonormal basis $\{\phi_n(x)\}$, there does seem to be a natural canonical representative $f_c \in [f]$, given by the generalized Fourier series for $[f]$:
$$f_c(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \langle f, \phi_n \rangle \phi_n, \qquad \qquad \langle f, \phi_n \rangle := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)\, \phi_n(x)\, d^nx.$$
Does this choice of section depend on the choice of basis $\{ \phi_n \}$? (Obviously it would be "nicer" if it didn't.)

Comment: I think the answer is mostly negative. For example, in $L^2[0,2\pi]$, looking at a Sturm-Liouville problem for $\Delta$ with two different boundary conditions, one being that $u(0)=0=u(2\pi)$ and the other being $u(0)=u(2\pi)$ and $u'(0)=u'(2\pi)$, we find two different sets of eigenfunctions. In the first case, $\sin(nx/2)$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. In the second, $1, \sin(nx), \cos(nx)$ for $1\le n\in \mathbb Z$. (Yes, half overlap.)  Already the constant function $1$'s expansion in the first basis cannot possibly converge at $0$...

Comment: @paulgarrett True, but I think that example's a bit different, because the function $1$ to be approximated doesn't obey the former set of boundary conditions, so clearly there are going to be problems at the boundary. I would imagine that things would work out "nicer" if you try to approximate a function in $\mathcal{L}^2$ as a series of basis functions for $L^2$, as you wouldn't have this problem with the boundary conditions.

Comment: The series you propose as a canonical representative only converges in general in L^2 and not pointwise everywhere.

Comment: I'd say take the Lebesgue representative, which is obtained taking the asymptotic average on smaller and smaller balls around a point. By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem this function coincides a.e. with the original one

Comment: @Del, does the limit in Lebesgue's theorem exist *everywhere*? The theorem is usually stated saying that for almost all points the limit exists and coincides with the original function, but I don't recall if the limit exists at all points and only convergence to $f$ is what may fail at a null set.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes you're right, it could be that it does not exist everywhere. I was thinking in terms of sets, where you can take as a representative of a measurable set the set of points of density $1$. However for functions maybe there is not a direct analogue.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_theory