# Is there a simple characterization of the functions for which the Fourier inversion theorem holds identically?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, quotient-spaces

I was thinking a little more about my [previous quesion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623989/are-the-canonical-representatives-of-the-hilbert-space-l2-basis-dependent) about whether there is a [natural section of canonical representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class#Notation_and_formal_definition) of the [quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)#Definition) from the space $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ of square-integrable functions to the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (in which we mod out the kernel of the $L^2$ norm). Another possibility occurs to me, which is manifestly basis-independent.

The Fourier transform is a [unitary operator on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_L2). The Fourier inversion theorem [holds almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Conditions_on_the_function) for functions $f \in \mathcal{L}^2$; that is, $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}f)(x)$ and $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}^{-1}f)(x)$ both agree with $f(x)$ almost everywhere. Since modding out by the kernel eliminates the "almost everywhere" subtlety, we have that $\mathcal{F} \mathcal{F}^{-1}$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ both equal the identity on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I think, although I'm not positive, that the transform $\mathcal{F} \mathcal{F}^{-1}$ and/or $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ actually implements the quotient map, in the sense that these transformations take all the functions in each equivalence class in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ to a single canonical representative. In this case, a natural section of the quotient map would be the set of functions $f \in \mathcal{L}^2$ for which the Fourier inversion theorem holds *everywhere*, rather than almost everywhere. Is this correct?

Comment: To define $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathcal{F}$ on $L^2$, cut out $|\xi| > n$ in the inverse Fourier transform integral, ie. look at $A_n f = f \ast   \frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{  \pi x}$. Then $(A_n f)_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions converging to $f$ in $L^2$ and $A_n f$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere. Set $A f(x)= \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n f(x)$ if it converges and $A f(x) = 0$ if it diverges.  Then yes $A^2 f = Af$ pointwise. $A$ acts as we want on $C^0$, but $A$ is not compatible with limits.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily get convergence everywhere for $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}f$. So your choice of $f$ would not be defined everywhere using this methodology. It is true that $\mathcal{F}f$ and $\mathcal{F}g$ are identical if $f=g$ a.e. because these are defined through limits of integrals. So that means you're generally not going to be able to find an $f$ in the equivalence class for which $\mathcal{F}^{-1}\mathcal{F}f$ converges everywhere.

Comment: Is there a simple characterization of $f$'s such that $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathcal{F} f$ converges everywhere?

Comment: @tparker What do you mean with "converges" ? That's why in my comment I started by defining $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathcal{F}$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty} f \ast   \frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{  \pi x}$ (limit in $L^2$). Also my operator $A$  acts as we want on $C^0 \cap L^1$ not $C^0 \cap L^2$.